# Labels with subequations

Tags: align, subequations

I would like to align the equation like this but instead have the label (40.a) and (40.b) for the last two lines. I don't know how to do this with subequations because of the \times\left{ that should be aligned with the =.

[image]

The code (moved from comment):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray} 
\begin{array}{cl} a & =b(x)\[10pt] & \times\left\{ \begin{matrix}   c&\text{if }x<1, \[10pt] d&\text{if }x>1.   
\end{matrix} \right. 
\end{array} 
\end{eqnarray}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide code by which you generate showed equation. For what you looking for: use `\begin{subequations} ...<equations>...\end{subequations}`.

Comment: I use
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{cl}
   a&=b(x)\\[10pt]
 &\times\left\{
  \begin{matrix} c&\text{if }x<1,  \\[10pt]
     d&\text{if }x>1.  
  \end{matrix} 
 \right.
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}.  
I don't know how to do this using subequations.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add your comment inside it! And add missing preamble etc, that code can be compiled. This time I will do this for you ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into using the `numcases` environment of the [cases](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cases/) package (which you should load with the option `subnum`).

Incidentally, don't use the `eqnarray` environment -- *it's badly deprecated*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subnum]{cases}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{39} % just for this example

\begin{numcases}{a = b(x) \times}
  c & for $x<1$\\
  d & for $x>1$
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I looked at numcases but it's not exactly what I want, the expression b(x) is pretty lentgthy that's why II want the cases in another line.

Comment: @user107878 - It would have been really useful if you'd mentioned up front that "`b(x)`" is "pretty lengthy".